# Copy all string outputs from a loop (not in a list)

Tags: python, string, list, append

I have the following sample code:

```
from pyperclip import copy

numbers = [1,2,3]

for i in range (1,len(numbers)):

    text1 = 'Hi' + str(i) + '\n'
    text2 = 'Hello' + str(i) + '\n'
    
    copy(text1 + text2)

# Hi 3
# Hello 3
```

I tried appending the text into a list, but I'm not able to get the same output as I want.

Instead of getting the last output of the loop, I want to get the following output:

```
Hi 1
Hello 1
Hi 2
Hello 2
Hi 3
Hello 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
from pyperclip import copy

numbers = [1, 2, 3]

tmp = []
for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
    text1 = 'Hi' + str(i) + '\n'
    text2 = 'Hello' + str(i) + '\n'

    tmp.append(text1 + text2)  # <-- accumulate all the values

copy("".join(tmp)) # <-- Copy outside of the loop̵
```

Comment: Thank You Sushanth for your answer! It worked

Answer (score 0):

Or give this a try

```py
copy("\n".join(f'Hi {i}\nHello {i}' for i in [1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
text_array = []

for i in numbers:
    text1 = "Hi " + str(i)
    text2 = "Hello " + str(i)
    text_array.append(text1)
    text_array.append(text2)

for i in text_array:
    print i
```

It should give you the output you wanted.